# EF Core 2.0: How to discover the exact object, in object graph, causing error in a insert operation?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a complex and big object graph that I want to insert in database by using a DbContext and SaveChanges method.

This object is a result of parsing a text file with 40k lines (around 3MB of data). Some collections inside this object have thousands of items.

I am able to parse the file correctly and add it to the context so that it can start tracking the object. But when I try to SaveChanges, it says:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.

I would like to know if there is a smart and efficient way of discovering which object is causing the issue. It seems that a varchar field is too little to store the data. But it's a lot of tables and fields to check manually.

I would like to get a more specific error somehow. I already configured an **ILoggerProvider** and added the **EnableSensitiveDataLogging** option in my dbContext to be able to see which sql queries are being generated. I even added **MiniProfiler** to be able to see the parameter values, because they are not present in the log generated by the dbContext.

Reading somewhere in the web, I found out that in EF6 there is some validation that happens before the sql is passed to the database to be executed. But it seems that in EF Core this is not available anymore. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the only approach I've found to solve this, is implementing some validation by overriding dbContext's SaveChanges method. I've made a merge of these two approaches to build mine:

[Implementing Missing Features in Entity Framework Core - Part 3](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/implementing-missing-features-in-entity-framework-core-part-3)

[Validation in EF Core](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/12/13/validation-in-efcore.html)

The result is...

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        ValidateEntities();

        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        ValidateEntities();

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void ValidateEntities()
    {
        var serviceProvider = this.GetService<IServiceProvider>();
        var items = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        var entities = from entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                       where entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified
                       select entry.Entity;

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext(entity, serviceProvider, items);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, context, results, true)) continue;

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (result == ValidationResult.Success) continue;

                var errorMessage = $"{entity.GetType().Name}: {result.ErrorMessage}";
                throw new ValidationException(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that it's not necessary to override the other SaveChanges overloads, because they call these two.

Answer (score 0):

The Error tells you that youre writing more characters to a field than it can hold.
This error for example would be thrown when you create a given field as NVARCHAR(4) or CHAR(4) and write 'hello' to it.

So you could simply check the length of the values you read in to find the one which is causing your problem. There is at least on which is too long for a field.